# What is Dart equivalent to AS3 arguments object?

Tags: actionscript-3, dart

I am translating AS3 code into Dart. I have partially translated the following but I am stuck on how to handle the AS3 arguments object. Any guidance?

```
void setLabelTextColors([int upColor = 0, int overColor = 0, int downColor = 0]) {
  _lcUp = arguments.length > 0 ? upColor : -1;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the question mark operator to see if an argument has been given or not.

```
void setLabelTextColors([int upColor = 0, int overColor = 0, int downColor = 0]) {
  _lcUp = ?upColor ? upColor : -1;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Btw: the question mark operator is considered bad style by some developers (and there is a discussion of removing it again). One of the reasons is that it becomes difficult to wrap functions.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of Dart but this is the code conversion

```
lcUp = -1
if(upColor!=0){
  lcUp = upColor;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. If setLabelTextColors() is called with no arguments supplied (arguments.length equal to zero), the value for _lcUp should be -1.

Comment: Actually, you are wrong the default value for upColor will be 0 which is the first parameter. So if no parameters are passed into the function then upColor will default to 0 at which time arguments.length will also be 0. In my code lcUp will always be -1 until upColor has a value other then 0.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
void setLabelTextColors([int upColor, int overColor, int downColor]) {
  int _lcUp = (upColor!=null) ? upColor : -1;
  // ...
}
```

If your code should differ between "parameter not supplied" and "parameter is null", you can also use this instead:

```dart
void setLabelTextColors([int upColor, int overColor, int downColor]) {
  int _lcUp = (?upColor) ? upColor : -1;
  // ...
}
```

**UPDATE**
The second snippet will not work anymore at some point in the future - [see this issue.](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10466)